# What is the advantage to upgrade a website from 32-Bit to 64-Bit on a Cloud base Hosting?

Tags: c#, asp.net, 32bit-64bit

I have a website running on IIS 7.5, using C#, Asp.Net 4 and MS SQL 2008 R2, **hosted on Cloud Computer**.

Our Hosting Provider offers the opportunity yo switch from Process Mode: from 32-Bit to 64-Bit.

I give a tried today to the 64-Bit option, but at a quick look I cannot see any performance improvements.

Off course I will perform more testing in a hope to compare have some objective data.

My question are:

- Does 64-Bit Process consume more RAM that32-Bit One?
- Our Website has been compiled on 64-Bit machine, could I have some unexpected compatibility issues?
- Does Asp.Net 4 take advantage of a 64-bit Process?
- Does 64-Bit Use Double the RAM?

Thanks for your help!

Interesting article:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/64-bit#32-bit_vs_64-bit

Comment: What deal? Can you try a better word?

Comment: better served on serverfault but i dont think there will be much of a performance difference. You can only test the performance by putting rigorous load and traffic on the website to see how the 64-bit processor handles it as compared to 32-bit\

Comment: Thanks leppie for your comment, you are completely right. I updated my title. Do you think it make more sense now?

Comment: Thanks Pankaj Upadhyay, I did not think about serverfault, how can I migrate this question to serverfault site?

Comment: Given that the Q includes a question about .NET compilation, I'm not sure it belongs on serverfault entirely. Perhaps it should be split up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does 64-Bit Process consume more RAM that32-Bit One?

It will use more virtual memory (but it won't be double that of a 32 bit process) which will increase demands of the physical RAM. However, a 64 bit process has the ability to access far more virtual memory. A 32 bit windows process can only access 2GB of virtual memory but a 64 bit process can theoretically access 8TB of virtual memory (although the physical limit is much lower due to OS limitations, etc.).

> Our Website has been compiled on 64-Bit machine, could I have some
>   unexpected compatibility issues?

The OS on which the code was compiled shouldn't matter. What is important is the processor architecture which the code has been compiled *for*. If this is `x86`, then the site will run as 32 bit regardless of whether the host OS is 32 bit or 64 bit. If it is compiled for `AnyCPU`, then it will run as 64 bit on a 64 bit OS.

> Does Asp.Net 4 take advantage of a 64-bit Process?

Yes, in the way mentioned above (ability to address far more virtual memory).

> Does 64-Bit Use Double the RAM?

No. An equivalent 64 bit process will use more virtual memory but not double. An increase in virtual memory demands will, to a degree, translate to an increase in demand on physical RAM.

Comment: Thanks Adam for your reply, Does Asp.Net 4 take advantage of a 64-bit Process? Would you generally advice an upgrade to 64-bit?

Comment: I've updated my answer. I can't really advise whether you should do this without knowing more about the application. Generally, moving from 32 bit to 64 bit is a good thing, so long as the 64 bit env has sufficient RAM. As paulsm4 mentions, you should profile the app to see whether the benefit outweighs the cost. If you have low virtual memory requirements then there probably isn't a lot of benefit in switching.

Comment: Thanks Adam for your update. Off course a profile is necessary in taking a decision. I really appreciate your insight on this, help me to understand the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Q: Does 64-Bit Process consume more RAM that32-Bit One?
A: Yes, absolutely :)

Q: Our Website has been compiled on 64-Bit machine, could I have some unexpected compatibility issues?
A: It depends on what you mean by "compiled".
   A C# or ASP.Net application (just like a Java application) should be platform-agnostic - you can run the same binaries on both platforms.

General observation:
If you don't *need* 64-bit (i.e. if you don't need 2++GB address space), then stick with 32-bit.

If your database generally needs 4++GB, and if your database must reside on the same host as everything else (i.e. co-located with your web server and applications), then going 64-bit is probably a good idea.

The only way to know for sure is to profile your application.

You've done this already, haven't you ;)?

Comment: Thanks paulsm4, yes I haven't profile yet my Web Application :-) just I would like have a general feedback from your guys on the matter. PS: the DB is on another Server

Answer (score 0):

Your database server is the most likely component to benefit the most from stepping up to 64 bit. If your database data is larger than 3GB or so, stepping up to a 64 bit OS will give your database virtual address space breathing room. It may use more RAM than its 32 bit version, but that's not really the point. With a 64 bit address space, the database server has the option to memory map the database data 1:1 onto the virtual memory address space and vastly simplify its file I/O.  The OS kernel will swap pages of the database file into memory as it is referenced.

Depending on your app's database access patterns, and how much of your database data actually fits into the physical RAM available on the server, this can yield a performance improvement in data access times compared to running the same app on a 32 bit system and 32 bit database. The fact that 64 bit servers usually have more physical RAM than their 32 bit cousins will also improve database response times simply because more of the database data can be kept in memory and not have to wait for the disk I/O.

If your database data is smaller than 3GB, you won't see any significant performance improvement by moving to 64 bit.

Yes, 64 bit applications typically do use somewhat more RAM than 32 bit versions, but how much more depends entirely upon how the app is written. Pointers (object references) increase in size to 64 bits, but integer, double, and character data does not.

If the 64 bit system has the same amount of physical RAM as the 32 bit system, you probably won't see much performance improvement if any at all. But who builds a 2011 64 bit server with 2001 era 32 bit RAM capacity?  It doesn't happen.  Your 64 bit server will almost certainly have more phyisical RAM than the 32 bit server it replaces.

Is there risk of discovering compatibility issues in or bugs as a result of moving to 64 bit? Of course. Any change brings with it the risk of finding problems. Always have a plan B in case you run into an insurmountable problem. It's not likely that you'll you have problems but it's always possible.

Will ASP.NET benefit from upgrading to 64 bit? Unless your web server code is CPU bound or memory bound, probably not. Web servers tend to be I/O bound.  They spend a lot of time sitting around waiting for the next network request, or waiting for disk I/O. A superfast 64 bit processor with tons of RAM doesn't "wait any faster" for disk or network I/O than any other machine.